# DataSplice 5.1 CampMaster table does not exist in production, but exists in test environment

Tags: maximo, datasplice

We migrated some XML files (Views) from test to production. When the technician tried to create a work order, they got an error. The ds51prod.log said the following:

```
SelectSchemaQueryFailed: SELECT * FROM ds51_cm_offlineids
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Error Details:
Exception Type: DataSplice.Db.DbException
HRESULT: 0x80131600
Stack Trace:
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at DataSplice.Db.StatementBuilder.DataSplice.Db.Internal.StatementBuilder.IStatementBuilderInternal.GetAdoSchemaTable()
```

It has to do with the CampMaster plug-in not able to create the custom table as defined by DSAdmin.exe

[image]

Without resorting to creating the table manually, how do I have the application create the custom table that is missing in production?

Comment: Can someone please with 1500+ reputation add a tag called DataSplice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Run DSAdmin.exe
- Go to Display Views
- Look for Offline IDs
- Change Query Permission from true to false
- Click Save (diskette icon)
- Change Query Permission from false to true
- Click Save again

DataSplice should see that the table is missing and create it.

[image]

The issue occurred because the XML for Offline IDs had Query Permission set to true. When moved to production, this Option Value assumes the custom table already exists. The custom table does not exists and will error when DataSplice application wants to interact with the table.